# Optimizing Performance of Bulk Update of Existing MySQL Data

Tags: mysql, sql, matlab, performance, sql-update

I'm trying to perform a bulk update of around 200,000 existing MySQL rows. More specifically, I need to update eight empty LONG BLOB fields in these rows, each with a ~ 0.5 Mb file (LONG BLOB is used because there are some special cases where significantly large files are stored; however, these are not considered in this bulk update). The files that need to be inserted are stored locally on disk.

I'm using a MATLAB script I wrote to loop through each of the folders that store these files, read the files in and convert them to hexadecimal representations, then execute an UPDATE query to update the eight columns with the eight files for each row.

Initially, things ran fairly quickly; however, I noticed that after a couple thousand completed queries things really started to slow down. I did a bit of research on optimizing MySQL and InnoDB system variables and increased by `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 25G and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` to 25.

After this modification, things sped up again, but slowed down after another couple thousand queries. I did a little more research and tried to mess around with some other variables such as `innodb_log_buffer_size` and `innodb_log_file_size` increasing both to 100M just to see what would happen. I also set `innodb_write_io_threads` and `innodb_read_io_threads` to 16 as I am running this all on a fairly high-end server with 32 GB of RAM. Unfortunately, these modifications didn't help much and now I'm stuck with queries taking a few minutes each to complete.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how I can optimize this process and have it run as fast as possible?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: The throughput of your system is limited by i/o operations (the speed of your hdd). That it slows down is usually the effect of full read/write caches (including os cache that might have cached the actual source files) - but you eventually *have to* write to the disk. So please tell us the hdd speed, the (slower) update speed and if the sources are on the same disk as the database to estimate if it's too slow. Things you can try: Make sure that you identify your rows with an index (eg `update...where id=4`, id primary key). Commit regularly, but not after each row; try e.g. every 100-500 rows.

Comment: Hey Solarflare, we use a RAID 5 array of a couple of 4 TB SAS 6 Gb/s 7200 RPM server-grade HDDs that make up a total of around 36 TB of storage space. The source files are indeed on the same storage space as the database. Would moving the source files to another storage space increase performance? Also, I am identifying rows using a primary key index.

Comment: The system specs don't help much. Compare the max i/o (benchmark) to the actual i/o. Check e.g. the resource monitor for windows or iotop/dstat for linux. Compare that to your (slower) update throughput (e.g. if you insert 5 rows per second with exactly 8 times 0.5mb per row, read and write is 20mb/s), to check if i/o is the bottleneck. Having the source files on a different drive improves write speed (but if they are not, copying them first would have to be included in execution time). Also try the commit frequency. Also: maybe just keep the data in the filesystem/smb share and not in the db.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Solarflare. I think I identified the problem. I dropped all indexes except the primary key before starting the script because I assumed they would negatively impact the performance. I was wrong earlier when I said I was identifying rows in the UPDATE queries by primary key. I was actually identify rows by a secondary column that I dropped the index from. After running a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I saw that ~ 300+ sec. were spend fetching rows for the UPDATE queries. I re-added the index for this column and things have sped up a lot ever since.

Answer (score 1):

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8 will likely serve your requirements with less overhead.

innodb_log_buffer_size=10M would 'buffer' before writing to the innodb_log_file AFTER 10M has been accumulated in memory.  A ratio of buffer*10=log file size is reasonable.

When innodb_log_buffer_size is the same as innodb_log_file_size, you effectively have NO buffering.  Make buffer_size much less than log file size.